# Data structures in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am looking for a data structure that can mimic an Object or a struct. Really, just some compact way to pass around different types of variables. Currently I am using a tuple but referencing various parts of the tuple is less pleasant than I would like. Currently I've just created aliases that represent the various locations in the tuple:

```
alias AuxClass = tuple[str,str,list[int],list[int],Dec];
int ACLS = 0;
```

But I've had to restructure this tuple and thus had to change the indexing. Is there something I can use here that I've missed or perhaps a feature coming in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the algebraic data types feature:

http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Declarations/AlgebraicDataType/AlgebraicDataType.html

You can create a constructor to represent the type of data that you are trying to define above, similar to what you would do with a struct, and give each element in the constructor a field name:

`data AuxClass = auxClass(str f1, str f2, list[int] f3, list[int] f4, Dec f5)`

You can then create new instances of this just using the constructor name and providing the data:

`a = auxClass("Hello", "World", [1,2,3], [4,5,6], D1)` (where `D1` is a `Dec`).

Once you have an instance, you can access information using the field names:

`a.f1 // which equals "Hello"`

`a.f3 // which equals [1,2,3]`

`size(a.f3)` // which currently equals 3

and you can update information using the field names:

`a.f2 = "Rascal"`

`a.f4 = a.f4 + 7 // f4 is now [4,5,6,7]`

Algebraic data types are actually quite flexible, so there is a lot you can do with them beyond this. Feel free to look through the documentation and ask questions here.

Comment: yes! you could add keyword parameters to your example, also quite useful with their default values and being unordered; as in `data AuxClass = auxClass(int width = 1, int height = 1, int area = width * height);` and for adding them later: `data AuxClass(str color = "white");`